Calculate add-on amount
I'm making a table as below, in the table there are the following indicators: Target, Actual Result, Add-on Result, One time Add-on Result, Total Result, Progress and Completion Rate.

Total Result will be calculated by SUM(Actual Result + Add-on Result +  One time Add-on Result)
Completion Rate will be calculated by ROUND((((Total Result - Add-on Result - One time Add-on Result)/Progress) + Add-on Result + One time Add-on Result)/ Target,4).

I want to set limits of completion rate to 100% so I need to change Add-on Result (not One time Add-on Result). How can I calculate Add-on Result to match with my condition?



Target (A)
Actual Result (B)
Add-on Result (C)
One Time Add-on Result (D)
Total Result (E) = (B) + (C) + (D)
Progress (F)
Completion Rate(G) = Round((((E-C-D)/F)+C+D)/A,4)




5,406
3,468.63
1,500
207.2
5,175.83
82.1%
109.7%



So I want to reduce Add-on Result to make Completion Rate as 100%. It will not be 1,500 but something. But I don't know how to calculate.

Would you not just do:
=A1-D1-(B1/F1)


A1 is the Target.
D1 is subtracted for the One Time Add-on Result.
(B1/F1) adjusts the Actual Result based on Progress.

